# What is the detection limit of protocol in scRNA-seq

Tags: scrnaseq

In [Shapiro et al.](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrg3542), when discussing about loss of molecules as source of error in single-cell sequencing, it is written that:

> Another source of error is losses, which can be severe. The detection limit of published protocols is $5$–$10$ molecules of mRNA.

I used to think that the detection limit of a protocol was the average maximum number of molecules detected across cells in a scRNA-seq experiment. However, by working on the dataset provided by [The Tabula Muris Consortium et al. (pp)](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/early/2017/12/20/237446) I noticed that RNA raw counts often spikes to more than 10 molecules.

What is the actual meaning of detection limit of a protocol in scRNA-seq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The detection limit refers to the ability to detect a given gene/transcript. In this case, they're saying that a given transcript requires 5-10 copies in order to be likely detected (in other words, the loss rate is 80-90%, which is directly related to [a previous question of yours](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/3126/how-to-compute-the-chance-of-failing-to-detect-a-gene-given-the-detection-limit)).

Comment: Exactly, in that question I misunderstood the concept of detection limit. Now it's clear, thanks.